# Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Tags: 2010, custom-masterpage

I have this in my master page.

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="CreateSSCSite">
    <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

If the user meets the permissions then it returns:

```
<span>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=oiylGAjBYhJ%2Bvc6V%2B0b7wg%3D%3D"/>
</span>
```

How can I make it not return those infernal **span** tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding to iambriansreed's solution, you can put the comments in Literal controls around the SPSecurityTrimmedControls to prevent SPD from adding the extra rubbish. For example:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" text="&lt;!-- "/><SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="EditListItems" runat="server"><asp:Literal runat="server" text=" --&gt;"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=oiylGAjBYhJ%2Bvc6V%2B0b7wg%3D%3D"/>
<asp:Literal runat="server" text="&lt;!-- "/></SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl><asp:Literal runat="server" text=" --&gt;"/>
```

It's a bit annoying, but simpler than writing a new control.

If you're using SharePoint 2013's Publishing Infrastructure, the same example will look like this on an HTML master page:

```
<!--SPM:<asp:Literal Text="&lt;!&#45;&#45; " runat="server" />-->
<!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="CreateSSCSite">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:Literal Text=" &#45;&#45;&gt;" runat="server" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=oiylGAjBYhJ%2Bvc6V%2B0b7wg%3D%3D"/>
<!--SPM:<asp:Literal Text="&lt;!&#45;&#45; " runat="server" />-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:Literal Text=" &#45;&#45;&gt;" runat="server" />-->
```

Comment: Thank goodness that in SharePoint 2013 the heinous SP Designer is going away and other text editors can be used. :)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and cleanest way to do this is wrap the control with html comments:

```
<!-- <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="CreateSSCSite"> -->
    <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
<!-- </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl> -->
```

If the user meets the permissions then it returns:

```
<!-- <span> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=oiylGAjBYhJ%2Bvc6V%2B0b7wg%3D%3D"/>
<!-- </span> -->
```

Super simple.

Comment: Hiding the span tag this way is OK but in the editor mode SPD adds a bunch of crap. I am now looking for an alternative.

Comment: Clever. Very clever.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create your own control inheriting from Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl and override RenderBeginTag and RenderEndTag to do nothing

Comment: I read about that but it is amazingly ridiculous just to get SP not to print a span tag.

Comment: Yes, but SPSecurityTrimmedControl inherits from the ASP.Net WebControl, which is the one rendering the span tag

Comment: Can this be done without deploying a WSP?

Comment: No, this requires an WSP