# SharePoint 2013 edit page permission

Tags: 2013, permissions, edit

I have following requirement:-

1. Give only edit page permission to contributor on pages in SharePoint 2013 site. It means contributor member should be able to edit page but should not able to able create page.
2. The gear icon should only show edit page. It means site content and site settings should not be shown.

What I tried:-

On the site level I gave contributor read permission and On the site page library I break the permission and gave unique permission to contributor to edit but not create. Now user is able to edit page but not create. However site content and site settings are still appearing. How to hide it for contributor?

Answer (score 0):

There is an old discussion [how to hide view all site content](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/hide-site-actions-view-all-site-content-in-a-2010-publishing-site). Although it is talking about SP2010, most of the advice can be reused in SP2013.

Personally, I suggest edit your Master page to control the `site action menu`. According to [this blog](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/05/change-sharepoint-2013-site-actions/)

Here is a sample Site Actions menu item tag:

> " 
>   Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>" 
>   ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/ActionsEditPage.png?rev=23" 
>   MenuGroupId="200"  Sequence="210"  PermissionsString="EditListItems" 
>   ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);" />

By change the parameter `PermissionsString` you can control who can see this menu item (Edit Page). You can find a list of available value in [this blog](http://SPSecurityTrimmedControl%20%E2%80%93%20Possible%20Values%20for%20PermissionsString). In your case, you may want to limit "Edit Page" item to "ManageWeb".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply.

The permissionstring setting manage visibility of Site Actions by user in SharePoint. In my case i want to show the edit page in site action menu but don't want to show site content menu. This should work based on permission. If i just hide it then Contributor still can navigate through URL.

Is there any way to achieve this using permission level setting?

Regards,
Samit

Comment: If it works (or not) please let us know.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply. The permissionstring setting manage visibility of Site Actions by user in SharePoint. In my case i want to show the edit page in site action menu but don't want to show site content menu. This should work based on permission. If i just hide it then Contributor still can navigate through URL. Is there any way to achieve this using permission level setting?

Comment: I think it is an old topic since SP2007. All site content is shown to all users (even with read permission only) by design. You are suggested to configure correct permission on library/list level so that even he know the URL of all site content, he cannot see the files/items.

Comment: Thanks again. So in that case i am good to hide the site content. Now the next challenge is to hide it for only contributor group. If i put the css to hide then it will hide for all users. How can i restrict css to apply for only contributor group.

Comment: As I mentioned SPSecurityTrimmedControl  is your friend. You can wrap your css line with the control. [Check this out](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32053/sharepointspsecuritytrimmedcontrol)